# How to fix hundreds of leading underscores for local identifiers problem in flutter

Tags: flutter, lint, identifier, underscores

I've been developing this app for months now and this problems just showed up recently, is there a quick fix on this one? I don't want to fix them one by one

[image]

Comment: Looks like the file that defined the analysis rules for your linter is no longer where it was expected to be found. My guess is the defaults for that library don't like the leading underscores.

Comment: edit your linter

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to do all at once, but from that view you are showing you can right-click one of the error messages and choose "Remove leading underscores in file". So you can remove more than one at a time if you have multiple in a single file.